# Why doesn't nautilus display the Free Space of a partition?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

This feature was a really nice thing and its really difficult to get to know the free space available in a partition. Can't we get a tool-tip or something of that sort to display the free space.

Is there a way to get this feature back in ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That feature was available in the Nautilus statusbar, which is disabled by default (a floating, autohide statusbar is used now) for Nautilus 3. But you can re-enable it: in Nautilus, select View > Statusbar.

That's it :)

Comment: WOW.. It was that easy eh ? :P.. Superb :D

Answer (score 1):

If you open your desired folder in Nautilus, then right-click the background inside the window and choose Properties, you will get a window similar to this with free space shown near the bottom:

[image: Properties window]

Comment: Yes that can be done.. But is there a way to get back the old thing..

Comment: @Bhargav Unfortunately I don't have easy access to 11.04 right now...if you do, do you think you could add a screenshot to your question showing exactly what functionality you would like restored? This might give us a better idea of what you might want.

Comment: It was the status bar :D.. I'm sorry for not knowing the right Names .. I should known its called the status bar :P

Comment: @Bhargav Things can get confusing when you don't know the terminology for GUI components. You're not alone: I didn't know what the pane separator was called when I was trying to get help putting a dark sidebar in Ambiance. Anyways, thanks for clarifying.